# SwiftUI Button height on watchOS

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos

On iOS by default if you add the button in SwiftUI its size is equal to the size of the text. Setting the `padding` to some value expands the size to be bigger than the text by that value.

On watchOS by default the button has the text and background with applied padding. I don't see any way to reduce that padding (to make the button height closer to the height of the text). I have tried with setting `padding` and `frame` but it doesn't appear to be helpful - it appears even counter intuitive as increasing the `padding` reduces the height of the visible button but it keeps the overall size of the button in the layout which still isn't helpful.

Just to note that with storyboards this reduction of height is possible so I would assume that there should be a way in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the button’s buttonStyle(:) to PlainButtonStyle() and you’ll have full control over the padding and frame. The downside is that you no longer get the default button background, so you’ll need to recreate it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you still want the system styling, is to scale it down with `controlSize(_:)`

> Use controlSize(_:) to override the system default size for controls in this view. In this example, a view displays several typical controls at .mini, .small and .regular sizes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/controlsize(_:)